# Editable Radio Buttons (UX)

Tags: usability, radio-buttons, edit

[image: MockupImage]I need a way to select a date range and edit the date range. Also when a date range is selected it will show other dependent information.

My plan was to use radio buttons and whichever date range radio button is selected will be editable and that range's dependent information will show.

My question is are editable radio buttons common? Is there a better option?

Comment: Perhaps you could do a little mockup or wireframe of what you have in mind? Typically a checkbox, not a radio button, would be preferred if both the start and end date can be toggled on and off.

Comment: Image has been added. Checkboxes wouldn't work in this case because only one date range can be selected at a time.

Comment: Thanks for the image, I agree with you about checkboxes not being the right approach here, I'd imagined something different.

Comment: Sorry, the question seems a little unclear. If only one date range can be selected, why display 3? Why are the other two present when the user can just select date range from a single date picker?  You could then load the dependent  fields based on the dates chosen from the date picker.

Comment: The user needs the ability to edit and change all three of the dates at one time.

Comment: What is the user doing? Why are they doing it?

Comment: I think the Radio button is a good choice for a limited number of picks. So the question for you: What is the max number of ranges you can show? Because if the number of date ranges increased we need to pick another way to list options?

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, only the selected date range is editable. In this case, I would remove the date picker / calendar icon from the other rows.

In the current design, it's not immediately visible which date range the dependent fields are associated with: you could highlight the background of the selected date range and the dependent fields in the same color, to indicate a visual continuity between them. Another solution would be to insert the dependent fields immediately below the selected date range, which would remove any ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

The most common date range picking interface is calendar combine with type input. [[source]](https://www.nngroup.com/articles/date-input/) Base on your context you can choose alternative ranging inputs like these:

- [slider with graphical information](https://dribbble.com/shots/250543-Date-Range-Selector)
- [Linear with picking segment variation](https://oxcrx34285.i.lithium.com/t5/image/serverpage/image-id/7606iAA113B9542BEF2FB/image-size/large?v=1.0&px=999)
- [type input in sentence](https://cloud.netlifyusercontent.com/assets/344dbf88-fdf9-42bb-adb4-46f01eedd629/f10f352e-11a0-4078-94ff-7e2c75a26652/hioscar-conversational-large-opt.png)

If it's one of them better highly depends on your context. Your input choice is generally used and so more familiar for users.